# Is it considered bad manners to copy and paste a response to multiple questions that are similar?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I've noticed a number of questions on a particular topic that are very similar. Is it considered bad manners to copy and paste a common response to the similar questions?

If it is considered bad manners, can anyone suggest a different way?

Comment: Yes, it is bad. It is rare that the same answer would apply to the same questions and if it does, that suggests that some of these questions are duplicates that should be closed as such.

Comment: Also note that there is a kind of "auto-flagging" feature in SO for posting the same post several times to catch advertisers/spammers.

Comment: It's a bad idea to just copy/paste the answer, however it's OK to copy/paste the answer to a non-duplicate question providing you: A) include a link to the original post, B) post the copied content in a block quote, and C) add your own text explaining how the answer applies to that specific question. I recently posted this as [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173110/158605) to a very similar question, which explains in a bit more detail why a straight copy/paste is a bad idea. You might want to check it out :)

Answer (score 4):

I would say it is considered bad manners, and you run a decent likelihood of getting your answers flagged because of it.

If you see a number of questions where your answer is the correct answer for *all* of them, answer the oldest one, and then:

- if you have enough rep, vote to close the rest as a duplicate of the one you answered, or...
- if you don't have enough rep, flag the remaining questions as a duplicate of the one you answered

Comment: That decent likelihood is 100% - copy-pasted answers from the same user are automatically flagged by the system.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - that's pretty decent!

Comment: What if the questions are not themselves dupes (they are asking similar, but distinct things, that happen to all be explained/answered by the same piece of data)?

Comment: @Ben Barden: If two questions are sufficiently different to not warrant being marked as duplicates, it's very unlikely that they'll be answered with the exact same code and/or exact same wording copy-pasted verbatim across them both.